# ng-repeat pass to the component

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-components

Hi i am very new to angularjs web development with typescript and really stuck with a problem. I dont think it should be a hard problem yet i have spent two days on it.

I am trying to figure out how i can pass the value of an ng-repeat from a list to a child component when it's being constucted or initiated.

What i mean is, if i have a list([1, 2, 3, 4]) from the parent component that is used to generate 4 child components is there a way for each of the child components to assign a variable "id" to the value associated to the value of the repeat.

for example

```
<span ng-repeat=variable in list>
    <child-tag></child-tag>
</span>
```

Is it possible to somehow pass the variable into the constructor of the component from the tags or something?

Just to reiterate, I have coded this using typesccript with angularjs not angular 2.

Cheers in advance for the help.
And sorry in advance for what is probably a very simple answer but cant find it anywhere.

Comment: Read about directives

Comment: @AluanHaddad is that another way of saying its not possible :( ? Is it difficult to convert an already built component into a directive? oh and thanks for your comment

Comment: Components have inputs. That's how you pass information to them. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

Comment: @J.k quite the contrary, it is a way  of saying that it is possible. A component is just a kind of directive

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the data from parent to child component using Input. 
Inputs should be using `<` and `@` bindings. The `<` symbol denotes one-way bindings which are available since v1.5.

`=`: Two way binding. It uses dirty checking and can cause latency. It also watches bound properties in the component scope.

So if you need to pass some data to child component, you need to bind some attribute value to it . Ex:

```
<span ng-repeat="variable in list">
  <child-tag variable-name="variable.name" ></child-tag>
</span>
```

Inside your child component declaration bind these values so that you can access them:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).component('childComponent', {
        bindings: {
           variableName: '<'
        },
   controller: ....
```

You can access these values inside your component class using: `this.variableName`

You can choose to have one way or two binding as needed and can have as many objects/attributes passed to child as you want.